# The project update is invalid.\r\nParameter name: projectUpdate

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Trying to update ADO project process name, but getting below error

The project update is invalid.\r\nParameter name: projectUpdate

Request json

```
{
"id": "{projectid}",
"name": "testing name project",
"url": "https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/projects/{prjid}",
"state": "wellFormed",
"capabilities": {
    "processTemplate": {
        "templateName": "testtemplate",
        "templateTypeId": "{templateid}"
    },
    "versioncontrol": {
        "sourceControlType": "Git",
        "gitEnabled": "True",
        "tfvcEnabled": "False"
    }
},
"revision": 146,
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/jsfdsdjfj"
    },
    "collection": {
        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projectCollections/93485943859"
    },
    "web": {
        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/testing name project"
    }
},
"visibility": "organization",
"defaultTeam": {
    "id": "{teamid}",
    "name": "testing name project Team",
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{prjid}/teams/{teamid}"
},
"lastUpdateTime": "2023-06-07T05:46:29.54Z"
```

}

Following document: [MS ADO Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#request-body)